# How to change clang-10, llvm-10, etc to clang, llvm, etc.?

Tags: compiling, c, c++, clang, llvm

I use **Spacemacs**, and installed `llvm-10, clnag-10, clangd-10`, and all related packages, in **Debian 10**.

Used the following command to install `llvm`

$ `sudo bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`

Then, **changed** `clangd-10` to `clangd` using the following command:

$ `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clangd clangd /usr/bin/clangd-10 100`

Now, how can I change the other packages like `clang-10, llvm-10, lldb-10, lld-10` etc. to `clang, llvm, lldb, lld`, etc.?

Because, I have to **compile** like `$ clang-10 hello.c` instead of `$ clang hello.c`

Comment: Why not just add a hard or a soft link?

Comment: @fpmurphy **Thanks for your help**: 
There are many files of llvm-10 in `/usr/bin/`  folder. 
So, if I link the following 3 files, will that take care of other llvm-10 files? 
And, can I give a link to just 3 files only? 
`$ ln -s /usr/bin/clang-10 /usr/bin/clang`
`$ ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-10 /usr/bin/clang++`
`$ ln -s /usr/bin/clang-cpp-10 /usr/bin/clang-cpp`

Comment: Why not just use hard links?  `ln /usr/bin/clang-10 /usr/bin/clang` and so on.  Uses one less inode and is very slightly faster.

Comment: @fpmurphy Thanks again. Per your suggestion, I removed symlink, and added hardlink, for clang and clang++. clangd was already done earlier. And it works fine. Can you please make it as a structured answer so that I can accept it?